# How can I calculate Android's font padding?

Tags: android, android-layout

Anybody ever had to calculate how much font padding Android actually sets to it's text views when the default includeFontPadding attribute is used?

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: possibly using FontMetrics? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html

Comment: FontMetrics don't show that apparently. I've tried with includeFontPadding set to false and to true but the values returned by FontMetrics are the same in both cases.